# jQuery AJAX never runs success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I have a registration form on my website and I use jQuery's AJAX function to send the data into my ASP.NET API.

My AJAX looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '[urlHere]',
    data: {
        'Name': userName,
        'LastName': userLastName,
        'Email': userEmail,
        'Password': userPass
    },
    dataType: 'application/json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log('Success');
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log('Error');
    }
});
```

(The values in the data object are values I got from the inputs on my website)
The data I send into the API gets inserted into a SQL Database Table. Running this AJAX function successfully inserts my data into my Database, but it always runs the `error` function. I have tested the API in apps like Postman, and the API works perfect, but my AJAX always runs `error`. When I `console.log` the error that gets returned, it returns the statusCode of `OK`, which is what I set it to if everything goes successfully in the API.

Comment: Try `console.log`ging the *err* to see what the error is.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I edited my Question, read the last part again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery tends to call the error function for successful responses when it cannot parse the response to the desired data type. First of all, I don't believe `application/json` is a proper value for the `dataType` property. Change it to just `json` first. If that doesn't work, remove that line completely, log the response and verify whether your response is in fact a proper JSON.

Reference: [jQuery Ajax Data Types](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#data-types)

Comment: @Szab, your post answer my very old question about `jQuery` Ajax, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Set these codes in your ajax :

```
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 processData: false,
```